# Extract string using delemiter in shell scripting

Tags: string, shell, unix, scripting

Trying to extract strings using a delimiter in shell scripts:-
Below is the example and command used.

STRING is output of a query from DB, Below is the example

```
select '1'||'-'||'B'||'-'||'C' FROM DUAL; --- output is "1-B-C"
```

Below logic is used in .sh file to derive the three strings separately.

```
A=`echo $STRING | cut -d'-' -f 1`
B=`echo $STRING | cut -d'-' -f 2`
C=`echo $STRING | cut -d'-' -f 3`
```

1-B-C is the common output which is derived for all the three values. Requirement is to display all three values separately. Can you please suggest any fix?

Comment: If you don't get the expected result for A and B, your variable `STRING` does not contain what you think it does, as you easily can verify by doing a (i.e.) `echo 1-B-C| cut -d'-' -f 2`. Peek inside the variable by doing i.e. `printf %s "$STRING"|xxd`.

Comment: The output of the query is as expected. I have validated the log file and the output is as expected. We need to convert the String to 3 different values using the delimiter which is not working as expected, can you please suggest any alternatives to fix the issue.

Comment: Did you do the two commands I wrote in my comment?